# Add dynamic id to a jquery selector

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a plugin named as **Ladda** which basically does is adds a loader when the button in clicked! I am populating a table from the database and adding these button in the last column of every row! Here's my initial code

```
<?php

                $query="select client_id,fullname,email,status
                 from atom_users ORDER BY id DESC";

                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                if($stmt){
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($id,$fullname,$email,$status);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
                    {

        ?>
         <tr>
        <td><?= $id?></td>
        <td><?= $fullname?></td>
        <td><?= $email?></td>
        <td><?= str_replace("-"," ",$status)?></td>
        <?= ($status=="archive" ? $status2='Un-Archive' : $status2="Archive");?>
        <td>

                <button class="ladda-button <?=$id?>" data-color="green" data-style="expand-left" onclick="val('<?= $id?>','<?= $status2?>')">
                <?= $status2?>
                </button>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <?php } 
                    $stmt->close();
                } ?>
```

What am I doing here is fairly simple just outputting data and in this code there is button! Now for every button to be unique I've added an `$id` variable to class of each button so that when loader is run on click of a button it runs on the button that is pressed. Now here's the function:

```
function val(id,status){
      alert(id);
      alert(status);
       //original line
       //var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '.button-demo #btn' ) );
         //dynamic 
            var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '."'.+id+.'"' ) );
            l.start();
            }
```

Now the issue is straight forward the two lines

```
var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '."'.+id+.'"' ) );
            l.start();
```

are creating the loader now I want to add the id received in the function into the querySelector so that it works dynamically I have tried a lot but it is not accepting id! any recommendations?

Comment: Why is your `id` wrapped in its own quotes? Essentially, your `querySelector` is rendering as `document.querySelector('."elementID"')`.

Comment: tried that as well doesn't work

Comment: `$("#"+ elementID)` try this one

Comment: Well you're also doing `.+id+.` - Why the additional `.`s? It should just be `+id+`

Comment: @guradio error returned: SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: @Santi error returned: SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: Can you change it just to `document.querySelector("."+id)`

Comment: just a sec! is integer class name valid? i tried it by just giving a hardcoded id like  var l = Ladda.create( document.querySelector( '.698323781740' ) ); it still gives me an error and the id exists in the class i verified on elements

Comment: @uneebmeer Classes and IDs that start with numbers will **not** work with standard selectors.

Comment: ya i reasearch and got a better idea...

Comment: exactly that what i just did! and it worked! thanks santi,can you add your answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had mentioned, your ID is a number. While it's acceptable in HTML for ID's and classes to start with numbers, selectors *will not work properly* for these.

So, first, you can prefix your class so that it doesn't start with a number. This will allow us to find it without having to do any crazy escaping with our selectors:

```
<button class="ladda-button myClass_<?=$id?>" data-color="green" data-style="expand-left" onclick="val('<?= $id?>','<?= $status2?>')">
```

Now that our class is "findable", we can modify the `querySelector` to find it properly:

```
var l = Ladda.create(document.querySelector(".myClass_"+id));
```

This should solve your issue.